# fopen is blocking wordpress even if i'm setting it as non blocking. Is it my server fault?

Tags: php, wordpress, fopen

I'm having issue with wordpress WP_Cron on a server with cUrl disabled, basically calling the cron blocks the server and i'm wondering why this happen and if it's related to some config of my webserver.

This is the code

```
    $arrContext = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method' => strtoupper($r['method']),
            'user_agent' => $r['user-agent'],
            'max_redirects' => $r['redirection'] + 1, // See #11557
            'protocol_version' => (float) $r['httpversion'],
            'header' => $strHeaders,
            'ignore_errors' => true, // Return non-200 requests.
            'timeout' => $r['timeout'],// here i have 10
            'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => $ssl_verify,
                    'verify_host' => $ssl_verify
            )
        )
    );

    $proxy = new WP_HTTP_Proxy();

    if ( $proxy->is_enabled() && $proxy->send_through_proxy( $url ) ) {
        $arrContext['http']['proxy'] = 'tcp://' . $proxy->host() . ':' . $proxy->port();
        $arrContext['http']['request_fulluri'] = true;

        // We only support Basic authentication so this will only work if that is what your proxy supports.
        if ( $proxy->use_authentication() )
            $arrContext['http']['header'] .= $proxy->authentication_header() . "\r\n";
    }

    if ( ! empty($r['body'] ) )
        $arrContext['http']['content'] = $r['body'];

    $context = stream_context_create($arrContext);

    if ( !WP_DEBUG )
        $handle = @fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
    else
        $handle = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);
            error_log('after');
    if ( ! $handle )
        return new WP_Error('http_request_failed', sprintf(__('Could not open handle for fopen() to %s'), $url));

    $timeout = (int) floor( $r['timeout'] );
    $utimeout = $timeout == $r['timeout'] ? 0 : 1000000 * $r['timeout'] % 1000000;
    stream_set_timeout( $handle, $timeout, $utimeout );

    if ( ! $r['blocking'] ) {
        stream_set_blocking($handle, 0);
        fclose($handle);
        return array( 'headers' => array(), 'body' => '', 'response' => array('code' => false, 'message' => false), 'cookies' => array() );
    }
```

If i set a timeout of 10 the error log is never printed for the call to the wp_cron and get this error instead

> PHP Warning:  fopen(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1350494198.1313750743865966796875) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 925

Is it some config on my server that causes this?I thought that calling `fopen()` didn't mean waiting for the resource to respond right?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the timeout is very very short (something like 0.01 seconds) since sometimes requests fail and, basically, wp_cron can try again next time. You seem to have changed it to a very long interval, and it is thus noticeable. Have a look at [this Trac thread](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11831). If you have `define('WP_DEBUG',true);` you will see this all the time. I think you may be worried about nothing significant. Is it actually causing trouble? For myself, I have never noticed a problem because of it.

Comment: Yes i know that, but basically fopen doesn't allow non blocking calls. But fsocket does. Read this track http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18738